# Can I use redux-thunk with socket.io or do I need to build a custom middleware?

Tags: reactjs, sockets, redux, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to practice crud app with socket.io. I want to use redux for state management but not sure what middleware i need to use though. Is redux-thunk ok to use with socket.io?

This is what my basic setup looks like.

I'm trying to practice crud app with socket.io. I want to use redux for state management but not sure what middleware i need to use though. Is redux-thunk ok to use with socket.io?

This is what my basic setup looks like.

```
//App.js

const App = () => {
   let socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000");
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const state = useSelector((state) => state);
   console.log(state);

   useEffect(() => {
      socket.on("initialData", (res) => {
         dispatch(getData(res));
      });

      return () => {
         socket.disconnect();
      };
   }, [dispatch, socket]);
   return <div>app</div>;
};

export default App;




//action.js

export const getData = (data) => (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({
      type: "GET_DATA",
      payload: data,
   });
};




//reducer.js

export const reducers = (state = [], action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case "GET_DATA":
         return action.payload;
      default:
         return state;
   }
};



// rootReducer.js
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   reducers,
});


// store.js
export const localStore = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd investigate what [redux-websocket-bridge](https://github.com/compulim/redux-websocket-bridge) does. In the end you probably want to dispatch actions that send WebSocket messages, and handle incoming WebSocket messages in reducers. That would be a good way to connect the flux paradigm with WebSocket's event listening and message sending.